# What's the differences between the VSTS Build tasks of docker

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

What's the differences between the VSTS Build tasks of docker (with preview) and docker without preview?

It's said in the description that 'red' ones can be used with Docker or Azure Container Registry, is this an only difference?

Could they differentiate with docker/compose version or environment (e.g., one for windows, one for linux?)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the source code of them, the difference between them is adding supported for Azure Container Registry, the Docker Registry Connection are the same.

You can setup a private build agent and add these tasks to a build definition and queue build with that build agent, and then these tasks will be downloaded to the _task folder (e.g. _work_task) and you can check it.